# Alternate colors on rows with merged cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to alternate row colors (simply for visibility's sake). I am running into issues where I am applying the rule to merged cells - it's still using the row numbers, even though the cells are merged together so if the first row is even, it is white and if the first row is odd it is grey. This is an issue because the number of rows in the merged cell is variable and I'm ending up with rows next to each other that are grey. Below is the formula I'm using right now.

`=AND(MOD(ROW( ),2),COUNTA($A1:$M1))`

Comment: a merged cell does always have the index of the top left cell which was used.
If you merge A1, B1, A2 and B2 the merged block has the name "A1" the next column is C1 and the next row A3